# Parse java source files and then modify the original source using ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR.
My goal is to upgrade our codebase to Hibernate 4, the newer version has deprecated the class 'HibernateCallback'. 
We have a huge codebase with thousands of reference to deprecated classes. 
This is what i have in mind:
1. Read Java source file(s)
2. Whenever we come across the following code:

```
getDao().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
                        public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
                                        throws HibernateException {
                                //Some code;
                        }
                });
```

3.Just before this code i would like to insert another line like this:

```
session.doWork(new Work(){
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conx) throws SQLException {
         //Some code from the previous pattern
        }
});
```

I have a working example - but it prints to stdout, i actually want to modify the very java file being read by antlr parser.

The example i followed in from the book 'ExtractInterfaceTool' - for extracting a java interface from a java class.

If this question has been answered then please accept my apologies - and kindly point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR 4 doesn't currently have any automated source *transformation* abilities, at least not in the core runtime. When I implemented a small refactoring operation for ANTLRWorks 2 (which uses ANTLR for parsing source files as they're edited), I used information from the parse tree to identify *where* to insert the additional code, but the actual insertion process is something I had to code myself.

Comment: Something like Context.StartToken.getLine(). So first save locations of all toBeInsertedTexts. Next edit file outside of ANTLR - since the very act of inserting will mess up the line number - so i guess one i has to start inserting from the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think source parsing will get you very far. Instead, I'd use [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) as IDE and perform a structural replace (Search / Replace on the AST). The mechanism is explained here: 
[Structural Search and Replace: What, Why, and How-to](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html)

The mechanism is not that easy to understand, but I guess it would look something like this:

```
$dao$().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
                        public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
                                        throws HibernateException {
                                $method_body$
                        }
                });
```

And the replacement would be along the lines of:

```
$session$.doWork(new Work(){
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conx) throws SQLException {
            $method_body$
        }
});
```

You need to tinker with the settings for the individual template variables, but the mechanism is very powerful. One huge advantage is that it doesn't rely on exact spelling or parameter typing, but allows wildcard types, method signature patterns etc.

Comment: Thanks Sean! It looks very interesting and powerful, i will have to spend some time understanding it first :-)